# how to add active class in framework nav menu when (add/edit) pages are opened

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, phalcon

I am using phalcon framework.
I want to active parent menu when children are opened in the framework terminology,

when add/edit pages are opened for example this is my menu:

```
                              /controller name/action name
Users                         /users
 - admins                     /admins
    ->add admin page          /admins/add
Sales
 - managers                   /managers
    ->edit managers page      /managers/edit
Inventory
```

So when I open add admin page i.e(website/admins/add) then users parent should be open how can I achieve that..?

Here is my nav menu page:

```
<nav class="navbar-default navbar-static-side" role="navigation">
<div class="sidebar-collapse">
<ul class="nav metismenu" id="side-menu" >
<li class="nav-header" >
    <a href="<?=$url->get('dashboard')?>" ></a>
</li>
<?php $check_menu=array();
foreach($this->session->get("auth")['menu'] as $m):?>
<?php  if (!in_array($m['parent'], $check_menu)) { ?>
    <li class=>
        <a href="">
            <i class="fa <?=strlen($m['icon'])?$m['icon']:'fa-th-large'?>"></i> 
            <span class="nav-label"><?=$m['parent']?></span>
            <span class="fa arrow"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
            <?php
            foreach($this->session->get("auth")['menu'] as $c):?>
            <?php if($c['parent']==$m['parent']):?>
            <li data-open="#admin_menu"  class="child_menu
            <?=$c['route']==$this->router->getControllerName()."/".
                $this->router->getActionName() || $c['route']==$this->router->getControllerName().
                $this->router->getActionName()?" open_me":""?> ">
                <a href="<?=$url->get($c['route'])?>"><?=$c['name']?></a>
            </li>
            <?php endif;?>
            <?php endforeach;
            ?>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <?php } array_push($check_menu,$m['parent']);?>
<?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

The current functionality is working only for admins page,I want to implement "When Add admin page(admins/add) is opened at that time also Users parent should be open"

Comment: Do you have an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: So you're just trying to add the class `open_me`? It seems your condition will never be true. The right side of your `==` needs a `."/".` between the controller and action to match the left.

Comment: I don't think your ternary operator is behaving correctly. You might try putting your conditions in parenthesis to ensure it's executed in the order you think.

Comment: You might also try `<?= $c['route'] ?>` for debugging purposes to see what you need the condition to match.

Comment: @Ultimater can u see my answer once and can u help with that.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?=$c['route']==$this->router->getControllerName()."/".$this->router->getActionName() 
|| $c['route']==$this->router->getControllerName().$this->router->getActionName()  
|| $c['route']==$this->router->getControllerName()?" open_me":""?> ">
```

I got the half solution by adding another or condition to check only the controller name.

example above is working fine only with index action BUT
There is a problem:

```
/users/                 == users/adduser            || usersadduser             || users
/craigslist/campaigns   == craigslist/addcampaign   || craigslistaddcampaign    || craigslist
```

second case it is coming with other action in that case it is not working.so is it possible to do in this way or not.?